# I want to be able to find all anagrams of a user input using a text file that I have loaded called words.txt, and need help making the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create code to go through the file, sort each word by lexicographical order, and then compare that to the lexicographically ordered user input. In my mind this should work, yet when I run it, my output doesn't give me any anagrams. Here is a copy of the statement:

```py
for word in wordunique:
    if word != user_input:
        if sorted(word) == sorted_user_input:
            anagram_list.append(word)

print ("Anagrams: ", anagram_list)
```

In this scenario,

- `wordunique` is the list of words;
- `user_input` is the user input obviously;
- `sorted_user_input` is user input but with all letters of
  the word sorted lexicographically;
- `anagram_list` is the empty list I
  am trying to fill and subsequently print out.

Yet when I print, `anagram_list` is still shown as empty. I am still very very new at coding, so I am apologize if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: please provide a minimum amount of code which reproduces your problem. your code here uses variable which are not deifned in the code you show

Comment: Can you share the code that defines wordunique? Have you verified that it works?

Comment: I would also recommend giving us some example inputs to use so that we can test out what you are saying.

Comment: I checked your code with 'cinema' and 'iceman'. It works fine and gives the output - `Anagrams:  ['cinema']`. Please share wordunique file to see what the issue is!